# Minimum Spanning Tree using Dijkstra algorithm

Tags: c++, dijkstra, minimum-spanning-tree

I got a graph with costs and letters on it. My task is not to find the best path from one node to another- this is finding a minimum spanning tree.

I did some table for that purpose and marked the best path for that tree.

[image]

[image]

but I do not know if I should go further from K node to another nodes or not. Still, the purpose is not finding the best path from A to K but MST.

Comment: path from K to H has cost 145

Answer (score 2):

Dijkstra's cannot be used to find the MST for a graph. It is a greedy algorithm which finds the shortest path between nodes. So, while it minimizes the cost of getting from one node to the others, it will not always produce the MST for the entire graph. The total weight of the edges from Dijkstra's may not equal the total weight of the MST.

Comment: I know that, but this was a test question, that's why I posted it ;)

Answer (score 2):

Dijkstra’s algorithm itself will not accurately find the Minimum Spanning Tree of a graph. It is meant to find the shortest path from a source vertex to every other vertex in the graph. Because of that, at every step, Dijkstra's algorithm will greedily select the next edge that is closest to the source vertex. It continues until the source vertex is connected to every other vertex in the graph. Therefore, along every step, the current graph that is produced is a spanning tree of the previous graph, but the sum of edge weights is not minimized because it only considers the vertices in relation to the source vertex.

However, Prim's Algorithm, which is used to produce a Minimum Spanning Tree, is very similar in procedure to Dijkstra's Algorithm. However, at each step, instead of picking the next edge that is closest to the current vertex, it greedily selects the next edge that is closest to any vertex currently in the Minimum Spanning Tree (the graph it is producing) at that step.